# Ubuntu generating some core dumps but not others

Tags: gcc, systemd-coredump

I set `ulimit -c 8` and ran this small C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>

int main() 
    {
    int x = 4;
    int y = 7;
    assert(x == 5);
    printf("\n Hello! \n\n"); 
    }
```

As expected, I got a message that the program was aborted at the "assert" line, and the core was dumped. However, I checked the current directory, and also `/var/crash`, and could not find the dump file. However, `/var/crash` did contain some other core dumps.

Comment: Does it work if you set `ulimit -c unlimited` ?

Comment: @steeldriver Still doesn't work :(. Though I did notice some strange behavior. When I open a new terminal, I am able to set `ulimit -c n` to whatever `n` I want. But after that, it does not let me choose any bigger `n`. It says `bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted` . It only permits me to reduce n.

Comment: Yes I'm not sure why that happens (even when `/etc/security/limits.conf` doesn't appear to place any hard or soft limits). Regardless, 8 (kilobytes - the default unit) is almost certainly too little - the core was 380K when I tried your little program (so `ulimit -c 1024` should work for example). Also depending on your Ubuntu version the default location for coredumps may be the current directory rather than /var/crash so check there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu core dumps are handled by Apport. To check (if it matters, my test computer is a server):

```
doug@s19:~/c$ sudo systemctl status apport.service
● apport.service - LSB: automatic crash report generation
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apport; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2022-03-22 15:35:56 PDT; 1 day 23h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 942 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apport start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 22 15:35:56 s19 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Mar 22 15:35:56 s19 apport[942]:  * Starting automatic crash report generation: apport
Mar 22 15:35:56 s19 systemd[1]: Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
Mar 22 15:35:56 s19 apport[942]:    ...done.
```

If I run your code, and look around (I used locate followed by a grep filter), then the file was in `/var/lib/apport/coredump`:

```
doug@s19:~/c$ ls -l /var/lib/apport/coredump
total 384
-r-------- 1 doug root 393216 Mar 24 15:16 core._home_doug_c_ask-1399109.1000.29f992b0-5950-4363-9cc6-9e99d17b3bd0.155465.17161959
```