# Log coredump file from systemd service?

Tags: server, 20.04, systemd, services, systemd-coredump

I'm running a mosquitto broker (2.0.14 from the dev ppa) on Ubuntu 20.04.4. Periodically, I'm seeing messages like the following:

```
Apr 18 07:44:19 mittServer systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Apr 18 07:44:19 mittServer systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I have not been able to find a definitive recipe for how to get coredump files to be saved somewhere for Ubuntu/systemd. But lots of overlapping things.

I did determine that I probably needed to add

```
LimitCORE=infinity
```

to the `[Service]` section of `/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service`

and then of course restart the service. Which I did.

But I'm not finding coredumps at either `/var/crash/` or `/var/lib/apport/coredump`. I did check to make sure `apport` is running per some older questions on this topic. It appears to be:

```
# systemctl status apport
● apport.service - LSB: automatic crash report generation
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apport; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2022-04-14 02:29:44 UTC; 4 days ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4475)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/apport.service
```

So I'm guessing either a) I'm looking in the wrong place for my corefiles OR b) there's a missing piece I need to enable/engage somewhere.

Comment: Hello. You are behind in updates. You list 20.04.2 as your version an up to date system is 20.04.4

Comment: Thanks. I used `cat /etc/*version*` to get my version. `cat /etc/os-release` shows that I am indeed at 20.04.4.

Comment: Look at the uname options for next time. uname --help

Comment: Do I get an answer to my real question now? :D

Comment: Yes, your status doesn't look exactly right, but I don't know what is wrong. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399109/ubuntu-generating-some-core-dumps-but-not-others/1399166#1399166), for example.

Comment: My theory is that that works fine (e.g. is enough) for normal core dumps, but not systemd ones.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was not enough to add to

```
LimitCORE=infinity
```

to the `[Service]` section of `/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service`. I needed to add both:

```
LimitCORE=infinity
User=mosquitto
```

to the file. The mosquitto broker downgrades its uid shortly after startup, and for some reason that meant coredumps didn't get written. I don't know if perhaps the ulimit that LimitCore applies only to the process while it's running in the original root context, and then doesn't apply once it shifts itself to another user.